# Grails 2.3 changes css font-face url to "resource:/..."

Tags: css, grails, fonts, font-face, grails-2.3

I want to include a custom font in my CSS like this:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: TheFont;
    src: url(fonts/SourceSansProLight.ttf);
}
```

The CSS is served with Grails 2.3 and the CSS is modified to become this

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: TheFont;
    src: url(resource:/css/fonts/fonts/SourceSansProLight.ttf);
}
```

The resulting font url scheme is unknown and browsers can't open that file. Chrome, for example, reports:

```
GET resource:/css/fonts/fonts/SourceSansProLight.ttf net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

/css/fonts is prepended to the original URL as well.

How can I instruct Grails to leave the font-face URL exactly as it is?

Comment: I usually use a path relative to the CSS file itself - e.g. `../images/foo.jpg`.

Comment: Also you can try http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline plugin, it will convert path under the hood

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution was to disable CSS processing in Config.groovy:

```
grails.resources.rewrite.css = false
```

I found the tip how to do that on the [Grails mailing list](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Disable-image-url-rewrite-in-css-in-resource-plugin-td4628381.html).

Comment: I really dont undestand what this do, but i put it in my Config.groovy and starts throwing a strange error

Answer (score 6):

A better solution I think is proposed by [dmahapatro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2051952/dmahapatro) at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22849288/2286664

You need to ensure your font files are known to the Resources plugin.

The following worked for me in my `Config.groovy`, adapt it based on your paths:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = [
    '/images/**', '/css/**', '/js/**', '/img/**', '/fonts/**'
]
```

You'll needed to run `grails clean` after making this change.

Comment: throw the same error with complete clean/compile/run-app

Comment: This ended up being the better answer than the one that was listed above. Wish yours was marked correct instead.