# How to link to an image from a CSS file when using the resource plugin 1.2.14

Tags: css, grails, grails-plugin

I recently upgraded to grails resource plugin 1.2.14 from 1.2 and now any image files I had set as background in my CSS file have 'resource:' appended to the url, which doesn't resolve.  If I manually remove the 'resource:' in the webpage it works.

How do I fix this issue, or alternatively remove the 'resource:'?

Note: the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623584/urls-within-css-files-broken-with-grails-resources-plugin-1-2-7) doesn't seem to work.
Grails: 2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like adding `grails.resources.rewrite.css = false` can solve my problem. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089379/grails-2-3-changes-css-font-face-url-to-resource).