# Grails resources not working with cache-busting CKEditor release (4.5.5+)

Tags: grails, ckeditor, grails-resources-plugin

I am unable to get a Grails 2.5.2 application using the resources plugin to handle the [cache-busting change made to CKEditor](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10685). The resources plugin is configured as follows:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/js/*', '/images/*', '/css/*', '/plugins/*', '/thirdparty/*', '/templates/*']
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['/js/**', '/images/**', '/css/**', '/plugins/**', '/thirdparty/**', '/templates/**']
```

The CKEditor code is placed under `app-dir/web-app/thirdparty/ckeditor` and is currently at version 4.5.9. The cache-busting change was made in 4.5.5, and version 4.5.4 works perfectly with grails `resources`.

I get the following error in the console when running the app with 4.5.9:

```
GET resource:/thirdparty/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png?t=a35abfe net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

It seems that the `resources` plugin is not coping well with values in ckeditor's editor.css file (a file served by the app points to `app-dir/thirdparty/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor.css?t=G4CD` as `http://localhost:8080/app-dir/static/thirdparty/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor.css?t=G4CD`). If I look at this file directly, it contains the following for the icons.png and icons_hidpi.png files, indicating that the `resources` plugin is incorrectly replacing the image file link (all but the first, actually) with a "resource:/..." url that shouldn't need to be there, and hence the console error. Curiously, it is only the icons.png and icons_hidpi.png files with their t parameter that get changed in this manner, other image files in the same `editor.css` file are left alone.

```
.cke_button__bold_icon {background: url(icons.png?t=a35abfe) no-repeat 0 -0px !important;}
.cke_button__italic_icon {background: url(resource:/thirdparty/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png?t=a35abfe) no-repeat 0 -24px !important;}
.cke_button__strike_icon {background: url(resource:/thirdparty/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png?t=a35abfe) no-repeat 0 -48px !important;}
.cke_button__subscript_icon {background: url(resource:/thirdparty/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png?t=a35abfe) no-repeat 0 -72px !important;}
```

If I add the following configuration, the app runs and displays perfectly.

`grails.resources.processing.enabled = false`

If I use

`grails.resources.mappers.cssrewriter.excludes = ['/thirdparty/ckeditor/skins/moono/**']`

in an attempt to prevent `resources` from modifying `ckeditor's editor.css` file, nothing seems to change.

What can I do? I can't leave ckeditor at 4.5.4, as there is an interaction with it that I'm trying to fix. I'm already using the same configuration [as recommended in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623584/urls-within-css-files-broken-with-grails-resources-plugin-1-2-7), but that does not fix the problem. [Disabling css rewriting altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089379/grails-2-3-changes-css-font-face-url-to-resource) just breaks other plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eventual solution (recommended by a colleague) is to exclude the specific CSS file(s) from being processed by `grails resources`:

```
resource url:"thirdparty/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor.css", exclude: "*"
```

This avoids affecting other files that were either unaffected by the upgraded CKEditor, or benefited from the processing done by `grails resources`.

Comment: After trying a lot of other proposed solutions, only this one worked for me (same problem, but with Font Awesome and Grails 2.5.5). Thanks!